# This Query took 40 seconds anyway to speed its up ? the data in the database arent that many

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

so this query took 40 seconds to load, any way to speed it up? the framework that I used are *Laravel* and I need to show this data using ajax and this query took 40 seconds to load, I need to speed it up, I know the r.10 - r.13 the one that caused it I tested it out and found out that 3 are taking almost 20 secs to load

```
SELECT
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`kdPaketBerjalan` as `r1`,
    `ms_pelanggan`.`namaLengkap` as `r2`,
    `ms_rtrwnet`.`kabupaten` as `r3`,
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`jenis_pelanggan` as `r4`,
    `ms_rtrwnet`.`nama` as `r5`,
    DATE_FORMAT(ms_paket_berjalan.tglpasang, "%d/%m/%Y") as r6,
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`noTelp` as `r7`,
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`terverifikasi` as `r8`,
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`hargaPaket` as `r9`,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(verifikasi_pelanggan.kdVerifikasi)
        FROM
            verifikasi_pelanggan
        WHERE
            verifikasi_pelanggan.kdPaketBerjalan = r1
    ) as r10,
    (
        SELECT
            verifikasi_pelanggan.statusVerifikasi
        FROM
            verifikasi_pelanggan
        WHERE
            verifikasi_pelanggan.kdPaketBerjalan = r1
        ORDER BY
            kdVerifikasi DESC
        LIMIT
            1
    ) as r11,
    (
        SELECT
            verifikasi_pelanggan.tanggalBa
        FROM
            verifikasi_pelanggan
        WHERE
            verifikasi_pelanggan.kdPaketBerjalan = r1
        ORDER BY
            kdVerifikasi DESC
        LIMIT
            1
    ) as r12,
    (
        SELECT
            COUNT(verifikasi_pelanggan.noBa)
        FROM
            verifikasi_pelanggan
        WHERE
            verifikasi_pelanggan.kdPaketBerjalan = r1
    ) as r13
FROM
    `ms_paket_berjalan`
    inner join `ms_pelanggan` on `ms_pelanggan`.`kdPelanggan` = `ms_paket_berjalan`.`kdPelanggan`
    inner join `ms_rtrwnet` on `ms_rtrwnet`.`kdRtRwNet` = `ms_pelanggan`.`kdRtRwNet`
    inner join `tr_resellerisp` on `tr_resellerisp`.`kdRtRwNet` = `ms_rtrwnet`.`kdRtRwNet`
    left join `verifikasi_pelanggan` on `ms_paket_berjalan`.`kdPaketBerjalan` = `verifikasi_pelanggan`.`kdPaketBerjalan`
WHERE
    `tr_resellerisp`.`kdIsp` = '11'
    and `ms_paket_berjalan`.`break` = '0'
    and `ms_paket_berjalan`.`deleted` = '0'
    and `ms_pelanggan`.`deleted` = '0'
    and `ms_pelanggan`.`suspended` = '0'
    and `tr_resellerisp`.`persetujuan` = '1'
    and `ms_paket_berjalan`.`terverifikasi` = '0'
    and (
        `ms_rtrwnet`.`nama` like '%%'
        or `ms_pelanggan`.`namaLengkap` like '%%'
    )
GROUP BY
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`kdPaketBerjalan`
ORDER BY
    `ms_paket_berjalan`.`tglpasang` DESC
LIMIT
    20 offset 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have an index on your `verifikasi_pelanggan` table, you need to.

To add an index run something like:

```
ALTER TABLE `verifikasi_pelanggan` 
ADD INDEX `index4` (`kdPaketBerjalan` ASC, `kdVerifikasi` DESC)
```

Just do that once and things should speed up.

EDIT: Your query without an index will scan the entire `verifikasi_pelanggan` multiple times for every result. Since it has an `ORDER BY` clause, it isn't even limited to 20, it will need to scan for every result and THEN sort and then limit to 20 results.

An INDEX essentially pre-sorts the table. It can find matches on the indexed columns almost instantly, rather than scanning and reading every row to see if it is a match.

Just indexing on `kdPaketBerjalan` should help a lot, but since you order by `kdVerifikasi` it looks like you might have multiple matches on `kdPaketBerjalan`, which would require sorting. Including `kdVerifikasi` in the index will find it instantly.

Comment: can u elaborate it, why adding an index would help the query much faster to load, I'm still learning SQL, also the query for DESC wont work and I just used the ASC one, and it still works

Comment: let us know your results.

Comment: I see thanks for the explanation, it speed it up from 40 secs to just 3 secs, I can see it now that the limit and order are the ones that causing it, the database that I used for this project is quite a mess, it doesn't have relations key and have thousands of record in each table, that explains why the app it self are slow.. anyway thanks for the help